# Subset based on repeated values in row and conditional in column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set of campaign contribution data. I want to extract the contributors that contributed in 2008 AND 2012 while keeping election type--I don't want to remove the letters in front of the years--P and G. For example, notice how AARONSON PAUL contributed in P2008, G2008, and G2012:

```
cand_nm party_id    contbr_nm       contb_receipt_amt   election_tp
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       250 P2008
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       100 G2008
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       500 G2008
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       500 G2008
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       500 G2012
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       281 G2012
Obama Barack    D   AARONSON PAUL       219 G2012
```

I want to extract contributors like this. My dataset was originally in two: eight and twelve before I combined them into 1. So I know that 21.6% that contributred in 2008, contributed in 2012 because:

```
length(unique(data$contbr_nm)) = 192022

length(unique(eight$contbr_nm)) = 123792

length(unique(twelve$contbr_nm)) = 95005

((123792+95005)-192022)/(123792) = 0.2162902
```

But how do I actually subset these contributors. I feel like there should be a way to do this with ddply or sqldf.

Comment: Maybe you could make a new variable... `Year <- as.numeric(substr(dat$election_tp,2,5))`, then subset to your hearts content, based on `Year %in% c(2008,2012)`

Comment: Is there any difference for you between `P` and `G`? Also, what do you mean by "extract"? You wan to keep entire rows for same contributor? Also, do you want to consider candidate somehow? In general, your example data isn't so good, because I guess you want to keep all rows here.

Comment: There is a difference--primary and general. And yes, I want to keep the entire rows for each contributor.

Comment: Either way, a rather inefficient way to create such index could be `df1$indx <- with(df1, ave(as.character(election_tp), contbr_nm, FUN = function(x) any(grepl("2008", x)) & any(grepl("2012", x))))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and [tidyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/tidyr.pdf) packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(year = extract_numeric(election_tp)) %>%
  group_by(contbr_nm) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(year) == 2)
```

It creates a new variable containing just the year value, then filters only for contributors who have two distinct values for that new variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a quick example that shows inclusion/exclusion

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(year = c("P2008","G2008","G2012", "G2008", "G2012"), name = c("x","x","x","yy","zz"), rnd = runif(5))
# You should use data <- data.table(data) here

setkey(data,name)

data[name == unique(merge(data[substr(year,2,5) == "2008"],data[substr(year,2,5) == "2012"])[["name"]])]
```

Breaking this down, I am inner joining a data table of all the 2008 values with all of the 2012 values, which returns all names present in each year. I then remove duplicates, and subset my initial data.table with names in this unique list.

Answer (score 0):

It would be clearer if you provided sample output but assuming you want to list which contributors contributed in both 2008 and 2012:

**sqldf**  SQL supports `like` where `%` is a wildcard:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select distinct contbr_nm 
       from (select contbr_nm from DF where election_tp like '%2008')
       join (select contbr_nm from DF where election_tp like '%2012')
       using (contbr_nm)")
```

giving:

```
      contbr_nm
1 AARONSON PAUL
```

**grepl/intersect/subset** This can also be done use `intersect`, `grepl` and `subset`. No packages are used:

```
intersect(subset(DF, grepl('2008', election_tp))$contbr_nm,
          subset(DF, grepl('2008', election_tp))$contbr_nm)
```

**Note** In the above we have used this as `DF`:

```
DF <-
structure(list(cand_nm = c("Obama Barack", "Obama Barack", "Obama Barack", 
"Obama Barack", "Obama Barack", "Obama Barack", "Obama Barack"
), party_id = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), contbr_nm = c("AARONSON PAUL", 
"AARONSON PAUL", "AARONSON PAUL", "AARONSON PAUL", "AARONSON PAUL", 
"AARONSON PAUL", "AARONSON PAUL"), contb_receipt_amt = c(250L, 
100L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 281L, 219L), election_tp = c("P2008", 
"G2008", "G2008", "G2008", "G2012", "G2012", "G2012")), .Names = c("cand_nm", 
"party_id", "contbr_nm", "contb_receipt_amt", "election_tp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```